# Confusion with elastic search data fetch and infinite scrolling on frontend

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, logic

I have a background service which pushed data to elastic search and will have a million or more data. In the frontend, i will want to fetch the data and implement an infinite scroll. So, i implemented scroll api. The problem is that the scroll time is to be set and there will not be real time data display if new data gets stored in the elastic server. I am stuck here. Could someone help me how do i solve this problem? Is there a better way? Basically, i want to display about 100 JSON when the component mounts in the frontend and display other data on infinite scroll plus, i want to display new data if a new one gets stored in the elastic server. Could someone give me an idea?

Comment: How is your data sorted? What happens if new data comes in, and given the way it is sorted, it should appear on a "page" that was already scrolled?

Comment: My data is sorted based on date. if new data is stored on the elastic server, i want to display on the top of the page i.e. the latest data will be in the front and on infinite scroll, the previous data appears, i.e. old data based on date.

Comment: So the more you scroll, the older the data gets... but if new data comes in it should appear at the top... if that's the case, then the Scroll API is definitely NOT what you need, because it doesn't allow you to go back and forth.

Comment: Is there something else that you would recommend? or maybe other approach?

Comment: You need to understand how your users will actually consume your data. Are they primarily interested in new data or old data? If the former, it's easy to refresh to top by retrieving the top-N most recent records. If the latter, you can paginate into the past using [`search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) and [PIT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html), but the scroll API is definitely not meant for real-time pagination.